# Почему переменная x и y не работают одинаково в фукции?

Tags: python-3.x

Сам код:

```
documents = [{"type": "age", "number": "10", "name": "ольга"}]

def get_ppl(num):
  for docs in documents:
    if num is docs["number"]:
      return docs["name"]

print("Введи 10")

x = input()
y = "10"
print(type(x), x)
print(type(y), y)
print(get_ppl(x))
print(get_ppl(y))

if x == y:
  print ("Почему не работает функция с переменной x?")
```

Результат:

```
Введи 10
10
<class 'str'> 10
<class 'str'> 10
None
ольга
Почему не работает функция с переменной x?
```

Почему в случае ввода 10 через input функция возвращает None?

Comment: Приведите конкретные тестовые примеры. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе.

Comment: Потому что is совсем не то же самое что ==

Comment: Понял, пошел учить матчасть. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

ошибка в данной строке:

```
if num == docs["number"]:
```

- оператор `==` проверяет равенство значений двух объектов
- оператор `is` проверяет идентичность самих объектов. Его используют, чтобы удостовериться, что переменные указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).